# Adding debug=browser query parameter has no effect

Tags: java, debugging, struts2, dev-mode

I'm debugging a Struts 2 application and trying to get the debugging interceptor to work.

In `struts.xml` I added this line and restarted Tomcat:

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

Next I added `?debug=browser` to an URL. Unfortunately this has no effect. The page just show as before, no debug information is visible.

What's missing?

Comment: can you show your full url (with obfuscated names, like foo/bar.action) and struts.xml ?

Comment: This was broken, fixed it and migrated to jQuery, you must wait for new release - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4322

Comment: Forget to add: you can test and report back :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a [Dojo plugin](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ajax-tags.html). More detailed information about [debugging](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/debugging.html) you can see  via following the link.

> "The browser mode adds an interactive page that display objects from
> the Value Stack (it requires the Dojo Plugin)"

Comment: Ok I managed to add the dojo plugin, also the provided link states that it's deprecated (I'm using struts 2.3.1.2). Anyway, adding the plugin has no effect.

Comment: If this is a versioning problem then refer to the version where it was working.